# %s expects type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int'

Tags: c

I'm new to C so we had this assignment to make, and I tried to make it more complex.

http://pastebin.com/A6z4MHGn

My current problem is making wordMin of type char* which I do not know why it is not already.

I tried making a similar, but shorter program

```
int numHrs = 2;
char* hours;

if (numHrs == 1) {
    hours = "hour";
} else {
    hours = "hours";
}

printf("\n%s\n\n", hours);
```

And here it works just fine.

Any feedback on my pastebin code is very much appreciated as I am new to coding and do not know the smartest way of doing things.

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself. However, note that you should post only as much code as needed and not your entire program -- so narrow it down a bit first. Also note that Stackoverflow is not a forum ([faq]) and pastebin does not fly here because questions should be able to stand on their own without supporting links.

Comment: Please, stop to add even more spurious stuff to the same question that has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 5):

When you define or declare your variables in one line:

```
char* wordHrs, wordMin, wordSec;
```

it means what first will have type pointer to char, and others just chars.
So define your variable in multiple lines, or just type asterics sign before every variable name that will be pointer:

```
char *wordHrs, *wordMin, *wordSec;
```

or

```
char* wordHrs;
char* wordMin;
char* wordSec;
```

Comment: This is why you should _never_ declare different variables on the same line. Apart from the obvious risk for bugs, it also makes the code _less_ readable.

Comment: The second alternative is misspelled; in C the asterisk belongs next to the identifier, not next to the type.

Comment: @Jens that is a matter of taste I believe ?

Comment: @MortenJensen I disagree; the reason is to exactly avoid the original problem/confusion. Every good C programmer (i.e. those who learnt their skills from K&R, *The C Programming Language*) writes it that way. Anyone writing it differently is a heretic :-) Is there even one single C book advocating the other style?

Comment: @Jens I've seen it discussed in a variety of books, some prefer the asterisk anchored to the type descriptor, others to the var name. All modern C books I've read, describe this as a matter of taste like indentation style and curly-brace placement.

Answer (score 1):

This line might be one of your problems (where `wordMin` is a `char[]`)

```
printf("%s", (char) wordMin);
```

Why would you be casting `wordMin`?

```
printf("%s", wordMin);
```

should work. An array of something (`char` in your case) always decays to a pointer to that "something" so a `char*`, here.

(The error message is a bit bogus since a `char` is converted to an `int` in the context of a call to `printf`)